# JQuery How to create element in created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, createelement

There is a [code](https://jsfiddle.net/md_bender/pj6a1akz/3/) I'm working on - https://jsfiddle.net/md_bender/pj6a1akz/3/. I need to create new elements and append them to the existing element ul. With creating elements and appending everything is OK.
But I don't know how to create child element in the created element. I need to create

```
<img src="path"/>
```

In the div I have created earlier in script. It must be like that

```
<div class="img-w js-popup">
    <img src="path"/>
</div>
<a href="delete.php">Delete</a>
```

But only I can do is create  as next sibling to the div

```
<div class="img-w js-popup"></div>
<img src="path"/>
<a href="delete.php">Delete</a>
```

Who can help me and solve my problem?

Comment: All it takes is moving one `)`: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/pj6a1akz/5/

Comment: Add all relevant code here at SO. If you can create fiddle sure you can create snippet.  click on `<>` to create a snippet in toolbar.

Comment: @ChrisG thank u! Everything Is working greate. I'm not good in jquery so i didn't imagine that I can enclose .append($('<img/>') in previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append `img` to `div` before you append that div to `li`. You can also write the same code like this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pj6a1akz/11/)

```js
$('<li/>')
  .append($('<div/>', {
    'class': 'img-w js-popup',
  }).append($('<img/>', {
    'src': '//www.gravatar.com/avatar/9142888a2ae6160f2faec90134eeafa3/?default=&s=80'
  })))
  .append($('<a/>', {
    href: 'delete.php',
    text: 'Delete'
  }))
  .appendTo('ul');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/9142888a2ae6160f2faec90134eeafa3/?default=&s=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <a href="delete.php">Delete</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because your `append()` call is on the `li` itself, not the `div` you just added. Try this:

```js
var $div = $('<div/>', { 
  'class': 'img-w js-popup' 
});
$('<img/>', { 
  'src': '//www.gravatar.com/avatar/9142888a2ae6160f2faec90134eeafa3/?default=&s=80' 
}).appendTo($div)
 
$('<li/>').append($div).append($('<a/>', {
  href: 'delete.php',
  text: 'Delete'
})).appendTo('ul');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/9142888a2ae6160f2faec90134eeafa3/?default=&s=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <a href="delete.php">Delete</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With that said, you're using the most verbose method of creating HTML. As you're hard-coding all attributes, it can be simplified by just providing the plain string - or even by just cloning the previous `li` and appending that.

Answer (score 0):

If do not need single DOMs (li, div, img) its easier to create static string and append whole into list, just like that (remember about backslashes):

```
$('ul').append("<li><div><img src=\"//www.gravatar.com/avatar/9142888a2ae6160f2faec90134eeafa3/?default=&s=80\" alt=\"\"/></div><a href=\"delete.php\">Delete</a></li>");
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer! I know that I can create elements in that way, but I didn't like it. Object style is more comfortable and have carefully look.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<li/>')
    .append($('<div/>', {
        'class': 'img-w js-popup',
    }))
    .append($('<div/>', {
        'id': 'idOFDiv'
    }))
    .append($('<a/>', {
        href: 'delete.php',
    text: 'Delete'
    }))
    .appendTo('ul');

 $("#idOFDiv").append($('<img/>', {
        'src': '//www.gravatar.com/avatar/9142888a2ae6160f2faec90134eeafa3/?default=&s=80'
    }));
```